# Regex to match 8 or 12 or 32 hex number

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex for a case-insensitive hex number that should match either 8 or 12 or 32 in length.

```
The regex I have so far is:

/^[0-9A-F]{8}|[0-9A-F]{12}|[0-9A-F]{32}$/i

The pattern I am trying to test against is:
96AFC4ADA8C44A36B0CB1EC28531C3BC

or

870b72a9a020

or

569ac61e
```

But this doesn't seem to be matching the criteria.

Can you help?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex exactly n OR m times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874777/regex-exactly-n-or-m-times)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
/^[0-9A-F]{8}([0-9A-F]{4}([0-9A-F]{20})?)?$/i
```

This will match 32 digits if the inner-most group is present, 12 digits if the middle group is present but not the inner-most group, and 8 digits if neither of the inner groups are present.

Comment: Is this case insensitve?

Comment: @Jake it is if you include the `i` flag (sorry I neglected that in the original version).

Answer (score 5):

Your approach was basically right, but you need to take `^` and `$` out of the alternatives, so they apply to the regexp as a whole:

```
/^(?:[0-9A-F]{8}|[0-9A-F]{12}|[0-9A-F]{32})$/i
```