# Regular expression only 7 or 13 numeric only characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently using regex: `/^\d+$/` to do numeric only field validation, but I have a need to extend this if possible with the following rules:

Only 7 numeric characters **OR** 13 numeric characters

Examples:

- **Pass**: 1234567
- **Pass**: 1234567890123
- **Fail**: 12345678
- **Fail**: 12345678901234
- **Fail**: 12@45!78901234
- **Fail**: 12@45!78
- **Fail**: 123

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874777/regex-exactly-n-or-m-times.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will work

```
/^(\d{13}|\d{7})$/
```

Comment: @indramurari Actually, it **does** provide an answer to the question. Why would say that it does not?

Comment: @torazaburo It shoud be comment. If it is an answer it should have very good explanation to it that why it will work as you have done it in your answer

Comment: @indramurari well, What I thought it's a really simple regexp. And the no ways I think it's just a comment.

Comment: Your solutions seems to work perfectly thanks Mritunjay!

Comment: @indramurari I agree that the answer could definitely use more explanation, but the lack of such explanation in and of itself does not mean that this "does not provide an answer to the question". If you don't like the lack of explanation, then down-vote it, but don't flag as "not an answer".

Answer (score 0):

Update regex with [limiting repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) with [pipe('|') symbol](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

```
/^(?:\d{7}|\d{13})$/
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/pHCVcQ/1)

Answer (score -1):

Where did you get stuck in solving this problem? You say

> Only 7 numeric characters OR 13 numeric characters

Normally, to match some number of things, we use what are called **quantifiers**, such as `*` for zero or more, `?` for one or more, `{n}` for exactly *n*, or `{n,}` for *n* or more, and `{n,m}` for between *n* and *m*.

However, there is no single quantifier that means "exactly *n* or *m* times".

Therefore, we have to implement the **OR** in your question using the concept in regexp called **alternation**, and is represented by the pipe (vertical bar, `|`). This is described in any [beginning regexp tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or).

So in your case, the relevant regexp is:

```
/^(REGEXP-FOR-7-CHARS|REGEXP-FOR-13-CHARS)$/
                     ^  ALTERNATION (PIPE/OR)
```

As other answers have already suggested, this turns into

```
/^(\d{7}|\d{13})$/
```

Comment: @Restuta No, actually I did not downvote it. Actually I like that solution. Maybe someone else downvoted it during the period when it was missing the `^` and `$`. It's not unreasonable to downvote wrong answers, and not everyone then reverses their vote when the problem is fixed. BTW have now cleaned up the comment stream.

Comment: agree, not sure why you think it's wrong when it's missing ^ and $. Like you said this is not the place to write exact regexes, that's why I prefixed it with "something like" and not "do exactly this"

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation @torazaburo

Answer (score -2):

You would have to do something like `/^\d{7}(\d{6})?$/` where `6 = 13 - 7`

I found this solution a little more flexible then say `/^(\d{7}|\d{13})$/` since it can also be used without anchors `^$` to match first 7 or first 13 numerical characters. Which maybe useful when you trying to extract data similar to what you are trying to validate.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874777/regex-exactly-n-or-m-times) for more details.