# OR condition for {} notation in Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression:

```
((?:4903|4905|4911|4936|6333|6759)[0-9]{12}|(?:4903|4905|4911|4936|6333|6759)[0-9]{14}))
```

You can notice that after the 4 digit numbers in `(?:4903|4905|4911|4936|6333|6759)[0-9]` I either need 12 number of digits or 14 number of digits. A condition equivalent to `[0-9]{12|14}`.

Is there a way to do this? Let me know if more clarifications are needed.

Comment: I believe this post address your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874777/regex-exactly-n-or-m-times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just `'[0-9]{12}($|[0-9]{2}$)'`?

```
>>> regex = re.compile('[0-9]{12}($|[0-9]{2}$)')
>>> for i in range(11, 15):
...     print(f'Match for string of length {i}: {re.match(regex, "0" * i) is not None}')
... 
Match for string of length 11: False
Match for string of length 12: True
Match for string of length 13: False
Match for string of length 14: True
```

If you wish to match 14 digit numbers that are not terminated by the end of the string, you will need to replace the `'$'` token with something else, such as `'?'`.

Comment: Thank you. Should have thought of this earlier. But I can't match the 14 digit number by replacing `'$'`

Comment: This is the regular expression that worked for me: ` `r'\b((?:4903|4905|4911|4936|6333|6759)[0-9]{12}(?:\b|[0-9]{2}\b))`. Accepting this because got the idea from you. Thank you so much

Comment: @MohitMotwani `'$'` represents the end of the string; you can use something else to represent the boundary, such as `' '` (empty space) or `[^0-9]` (non-numeric character). Anyway, good to hear that you solved your problem!