# JavaScript - Dynamic RegExp for Duplicate Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm very new to programming, and I'm trying to solve an exercise where you encode a string (in this case, a single word) based on whether or not the constituent characters occur twice or more. Characters occurring only once encode to, say "■", characters encoding twice or more encode to, say "X".

Example: input = "hippodrome" :: output = "■■XXX■■X■■"

I managed to solve it in a very convoluted way using nested loops and a `key:value` object storing `character:occurrences`, but i am trying to refactor the solution to be more efficient using a dynamically created RegExp, but i think i'm not understanding regex notation.

```
function encodeDupes(word) {
  let encoded = "";
  for (let char of word) {
    let regex = new RegExp(char + "{2,}","ig"); // create a regex to see if "char" occurs 2 or more times
    regex.test(word) ? encoded += "X" : encoded += "■"; // check this char against rest of word, push appropriately
  }
  return encoded;
}
```

it works with a more simple gate like `char < "m" ? do X : do Y`, and i thought i understood this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13874904/14297151) (`{n,}` = at least `n` occurrences), but i'm new enough that i'm still not sure if it's my regex or my logic.

thank you!

Comment: what about spaces, numbers and symbols?

Comment: @Cuong Le Ngoc i believe the exercise is only concerned with single words, as all the other test examples (not given here) are whitespace free, but i assume it should work for _any_ character in the input string.

Comment: update: @CuongLeNgoc your question was actually quite prescient =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm very new to programming, ..., I am trying to refactor the solution to be more efficient using a dynamically created RegExp...

That's a bit of a catch 22 because regular expressions trade efficiency for convenience. In order for the regular expression "engine" to run, a grammar must be established, and a lexer, parser, and evaluator transform the string-based input expressions into program output. It's (sometimes) convenient to implement a particular program using regular expressions, but it's almost impossible to beat out a fundamental algorithm that isn't slowed down by the regular expression engine.

> I managed to solve it in a very convoluted way using nested loops and a `key:value` object storing `character:occurrences` ...

Convoluted indeed, but sadly not uncommon to see even "expert" programmers do such things. An efficient algorithm emerges when we realise we don't need to count each letter. Instead, we only need to know whether a letter occurs *more than once*. Using two [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) objects, `once` and `more`, we can determine the answer without needing to allocate counter memory *per letter*! And sets are lightning fast, thanks to *O(1)* constant-time lookup -

```js
function encodeDupes(word)
{ const once = new Set
  const more = new Set
  
  for (const c of word)
    if (more.has(c))
      continue
    else if (once.has(c))
      (once.delete(c), more.add(c))
    else
      once.add(c)
      
  return Array
    .from(word, c => more.has(c) ? "X" : "■")
    .join("")
}

console.log(encodeDupes("hippodrome"))
```

Output

```
■■XXX■■X■■
```

Comment: although the examples given were only input strings of `/\w/`, the actual test battery against my original function generated random input strings containing `/\W/` as well, including regex control characters like `$^!(` etc. which made adjusting my regex increasingly untenable. this solution, aside from simply being more efficient _and_ sidestepping the control characters issue, also helped me solve two additional problems almost immediately, based on the way Sets operate. so thank you, Thank you ^.^

Comment: you now see the double-edged sword that is regexp. i love when things work out so nicely as you describe. it's my pleasure to help you. fun problem btw ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Usually RegExp are used to compare entire words or phrases.

Whenever `{n,}` is used, it's searching for two or more characters consecutively. Here's an example:

```
n{2,}
nn     # match
anna   # match
nan    # does not match
```

The following RegExp isn't perfect, but it should suffice, replacing `n` with the character of your choice

```
(.*n{2,}.*)|(.*n.*n.*)+

(.*n{2,}.*) —— for consecutive ‘n’s 
|  —— or
(.*n.*n.*)+ —— ‘n’s with anything in between
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: technically speaking, this answered my original question, specifically in regards to regex usage and me not realizing that `n{2,}` was referring _only_ to consecutive occurrences. it works perfectly with what i _thought_ were the test parameters based on the examples given (input strings of only `/\w/`). i later found those parameters to be... incorrect assumptions and/or incomplete examples. at any rate your answer was very helpful, even if the problem was eventually redefined.